# Python: Grouping similar words

Tags: python, python-3.x

New to python, have ran into a problem doing this task: there's a list of words, group them with the following rules:
They are similar if letters in only  are used to form  and vice versa, otherwise they are not.

For example:

```py
word_list = ['arts', 'rats', 'star', 'tars', 'start', 'pat', 'allergy', 'lager', 'largely', 'regally', 'apt',
             'potters', 'tap', 'bluest', 'tap', 'bluets', 'retraced', 'gallery', 'bustle', 'sublet', 'subtle', 'grab']

output = ['arts', 'rats', 'star', 'tars' and 'start'], [..., ....]
```

I am stuck for hours, how should I tackle this?

Comment: In those hours that you've been stuck, what have you tried? What did you expect to work and what did it do instead?

Comment: Looks like homework. We are here to help,please tell us what have you tried?

Comment: @AruneshSingh it is not, just a online course task so what I have been thinking is that I need to create a dict with alphabet in a word (let say arts) and match every other word's aplhabet with the dict. If the value of every key is 1 so they are the match. What I dont know is that do I need to repeat this process with every other word in the list? and how can I produce a list combining only this matched words?

Answer (score 2):

`collections.defaultdict` and `frozenset` (can't use `set` since it'd be mutable) lend to an elegant solution:

```
>>> import collections
>>> word_list = ['arts', 'rats', 'star', 'tars', 'start', 'pat', 'allergy', 'lager', 'largely', 'regally', 'apt',
...              'potters', 'tap', 'bluest', 'tap', 'bluets', 'retraced', 'gallery', 'bustle', 'sublet', 'subtle', 'grab']
>>> groups = collections.defaultdict(set)
>>> for word in word_list:
...     groups[frozenset(word)].add(word)
...
>>> print(groups)
defaultdict(<class 'set'>,
    {
        frozenset({'t', 'a', 's', 'r'}): {'rats', 'start', 'star', 'arts', 'tars'},
        frozenset({'t', 'p', 'a'}): {'pat', 'apt', 'tap'},
        frozenset({'g', 'e', 'y', 'l', 'r', 'a'}): {'allergy', 'gallery', 'largely', 'regally'},
        frozenset({'g', 'e', 'l', 'r', 'a'}): {'lager'},
        frozenset({'o', 'e', 's', 't', 'p', 'r'}): {'potters'},
        frozenset({'b', 'e', 'u', 's', 'l', 't'}): {'sublet', 'subtle', 'bluets', 'bustle', 'bluest'},
        frozenset({'e', 'd', 'c', 't', 'r', 'a'}): {'retraced'},
        frozenset({'g', 'b', 'r', 'a'}): {'grab'},
    })
>>>
```

Comment: Writing answers to "write my code plz" questions helps neither the SO platform, nor the people asking the questions - correct or otherwise.

Comment: I somewhat disagree, since posting the most elegant (I'm biased, of course) solutions to simple problems is useful for other folks coming across the question too.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
word_list = ['arts', 'rats', 'star', 'tars', 'start', 'pat', 'allergy', 'lager', 'largely', 'regally', 'apt',
             'potters', 'tap', 'bluest', 'tap', 'bluets', 'retraced', 'gallery', 'bustle', 'sublet', 'subtle', 'grab']

output = {}
def split(word):
    return [char for char in word]

for word in word_list:
    ascending_word = split(word)
    unique = "".join(set(sorted(ascending_word)))
    if unique not in output:
        output[unique] = []
    output[unique].append(word)

print(list(output.values()))
```

**Output**:

```
[['arts', 'rats', 'star', 'tars', 'start'], ['pat', 'apt', 'tap', 'tap'], ['allergy', 'largely', 'regal
ly', 'gallery'], ['lager'], ['potters'], ['bluest', 'bluets', 'bustle', 'sublet', 'subtle'], ['retraced
'], ['grab']]
```

Comment: in set(sorted(ascending_word)  I am getting a list of sorted alphabets in each words right? if i input 'arts' how come i get 'srat' in unique instead of 'arst'?

Comment: I want arst in unique so that I can get all words including these characters. You can add debugger and can check..

Answer (score 0):

Since the intent of the platform is learning by problem-solving I will try and help by describing a simple approach that you can adopt rather than giving you ready code.

Your problem looks like a grouping of [Anagrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anagram) together but with a small caveat. You can have a valid grouping even though the frequency of characters do **NOT** match.
For example, you have grouped ***rats*** & ***start*** together because both of them have the same type of characters. Hence your problem is now reduced to minimally finding out what all words have similar character compositions.
There are a variety of ways to proceed from here. I will be describing the algorithm:

```
loop the list 0..(N-1):
  use char-composition as key and push the entry to a list of the respective bucket
```

**char-composition**: All the unique characters in the word sorted. For eg, ***rats = arst*** as key.
Hence you will get all the relevant words grouped in the same bucket and then you can just print the corresponding list.